# `uvm_do_with with inline constraints

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I was using inline constraints in my sequence with the `uvm_do_with` macro and I came across something I don't quite understand. Hoping someone can shed some insight into this:

Assume my `my_seq_item` has 2 rand variables - `data` and `addr`

**my_sequence.sv**

```
class my_sequence extends uvm_sequence;
// Constructor, .... etc etc

virtual task body();
  my_sequence_item tx;
  bit [31:0] addr = 'h0101_0101;
  bit [31:0] data = 'hDEAD_BEEF;

  `uvm_do_with(tx , { tx.addr == addr;
                      tx.data == data;
                    });
endtask: body
```

This doesn’t play nice. Instead:

```
 `uvm_do_with(tx , { tx.addr == local::addr;
                     tx.data == local::data;
                   }
```

Works fine.

The other solution is naming my `local` variables something other than `addr` and `data`.

The expansion of the `uvm_do_with` macro says that it calls `item.randomize()`, so I assume in this case, the call would be

```
item.randomize(addr, data) with {addr == local::addr;
                                 data == local::data;
                                }
```

Does this mean that if the scope of the variables within the constraint block is that of item rather than the current object? If this is the case, then I should be able to call:

```
 `uvm_do_with(tx , { addr == local::addr;
                     data == local::data;
                   }
```

If this also true, then why does naming the variables to something else work?

Comment: I think yes, because when you apply inline constraint to any object, then you directly access the object variables, not through it;s hierarchy. Like `item.randomize with {addr == 1; data == 256;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-line constraints have complex identifier search semantics. It first searches the object that `randomize()` is called on (`item` in this case). If no identifiers are found, the search proceeds normally from the point where the call to `randomize()` occurs (from the `body()` task).

So when you have the same identifier names in both the item and the body, the constraint finds the `item` identifiers first. You don't have this problem when the names are not the same. Using `local::` is the way to show your intent that you do not want the item to be search. I suggest using `local::` whenever you just want the local scope search, regardless of when or not there are identifiers with the same names in the item.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification